# A question concerning the Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_m$ and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ denote two independent random samples from the same (continuous) distribution. Define 
\begin{align*}Z_{ij}= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } X_i<Y_j,\\
0 & \text{if } X_i>Y_j,\end{cases}\end{align*}and for $i=1,\ldots,m$, 
\begin{align*}U_i=\sum_{j=1}^nZ_{ij}.\end{align*}
From above definitions it seems to me that $U_1,\ldots,U_m$ are i.i.d. random variables. But from my calculations I've obtained that $\operatorname{Var}(U_1+\cdots+U_m)\neq\operatorname{Var}(U_1)+\cdots+\operatorname{Var}(U_m)$, where 
$U_1+\cdots+U_m$ is the statistic of the Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test. Are these random variables really independent?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $U_1 = n$. That event is more probable if the $Y$s are smaller than they are in a typical sample. That the $Y$s are smaller than they are in a a typical sample makes it more probable than it would otherwise be that $U_2= n$.  Therefore $U_1, U_2$ are not independent.